# ogr2ogr PostgreSQL driver doesn't seem to work with list of schemas

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I have a PostGIS database with a table `vector_data` in a non-default schema.  I use blue/green deployments for this database, so sometimes that table is in the `vectors_blue` schema, and sometimes it's in the `vectors_green` schema.  When I run `ogr2ogr` to select data from that table, I do not necessarily know (and shouldn't need to know) which schema (`_blue` or `_green`) is the current one.  That is, I don't expect to have to change my code every time there's a new database deployment.

[This GDAL documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg_advanced.html#connection-options-related-to-schemas-and-tables) seems to suggest that I can specify `schemas=schema_name[,schema_name2]` in the connection string in this use case.

Ok, so let's try that.  If the current schema is *known* to be `vectors_blue`, this works:

```bash
ogr2ogr -f "test.geojson" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=username password=password schemas=vectors_blue" -sql "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM vector_data LIMIT 1;"
```

But if I specify both possible schemas (because I don't actually know at runtime which schema is deployed), it fails:

```bash
ogr2ogr -f "test.geojson" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=username password=password schemas=vectors_blue,vectors_green" -sql "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM vector_data LIMIT 1;"
ERROR 1: ERROR:  relation "vector_data" does not exist
LINE 1: ...LCursor CURSOR for SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM vector_dat...
                                                             ^
```

Tested with GDAL 3.6.3.

What's going wrong here?

NOTE: Prior to GDAL 3.1.0, I did not have to specify the schema(s) because the PostGIS `search_path` controlled which schemas were searched for the queried table, but [that doesn't seem to work anymore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469339/why-doesnt-ogr2ogr-support-the-postgresql-schema-search-path).)

Comment: Do you know if both the schemas exist when you run the command? If one or both don't exist then the error is valid the schema doesn't exist. Perhaps try using an if/then statement to try one then the other if this is a binary option.

Comment: The schema list works for me with ogrinfo. Try `ogrinfo PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=username password=password schemas=vectors_blue,vectors_green"`. Does it list tables from both schemas? Obviously that was the use case for the option "to restrict the schemas that will be scanned while establishing the list of tables". It is also documented to be mostly outdated "The database opening should be significantly faster than in previous versions, so using tables= or schemas= options will not bring further noticeable speed-ups."

Comment: Which GDAL version did you use?  That `ogrinfo` command definitely fails (for me) using 3.1.0 and 3.6.3.  @user30184

Comment: I tried with GDAL 3.2.1. I included `schemas=public,lidar` into connection string and ogrinfo returns `1: lidar.test_dem
2: lidar.test_dem2 (Multi Point)
3: states (Multi Polygon, Unknown (any))
4: TesT (Point) ...`. All two tables from the schema "lidar" and then all the tables from the public schema.

Comment: Hrm - that didn't work for me using the `osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.2.1` Docker image.